# Custom service connector for DB2 service in pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-connectors

I have a spring boot app which i am trying to connect to DB2 service.But i am getting No service connection creator exception as pivotal cloud foundry has support for Mongo db and few other db's.Can anyone tell how to write custom service connector in spring boot app for DB2 service ?

Answer (score 0):

Create the DB2 service as a user-provided service using the command line:

```
cf cups db2-service -p "uri,user,password"
```

You will be prompted for the parameters. Enter user, password, and URI:

```
jdbc:db2://<host>[:<port>]/<database_name>
```

Make sure you have Cloud Connectors declared in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Bind the service to your app. Now you can access the database through declarations like:

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate _jdbcTemplate;
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Connectors directly supports DB2 as of version 1.2.0.RELEASE. If you are using this version (at a minimum), then this answer should work. What version of Connectors are you using?

Comment: If you are providing the URL as a JDBC URL, then you can name that parameter "jdbcUrl" instead of "uri" - e.g. "cf cups db2-service -p "jdbcUrl,user,password""

Comment: Thanks for ur response and sorry for late reply.I am using 1.2.0 Release version of jars.Actually there was some issue in the db2 jars.I am now able to connect to DB2 user provided Service but the app runs for sometime and then i get "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 4". exception

Comment: Also currently the credentials to DB2 are exposed in the Service URL's. Can you please tell how to avoid this either by encrypting or passing credentails in a different way ?  @ScottFrederick

Comment: I created service by only providing jdbcUrl in the format "jdbc:%s://%s:%d/%s:user=%s;password=%s' which is the format expected by DB2ServiceInfo class.This only worked for me and I was able to connect to DB2.Please help me to encrypt the url in PCF as I am providing the DB userName and password in it. @ScottFrederick

Comment: Did you find a solution to encrypting the password?

Comment: Yeah which one was the appropriate answer for this question